# "starts with" in an expression using DAX

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax

how can write an expression with DAX to check if a String starts by an other string ? example : ext.example starts with "ext."

Comment: `Mid(someValue, 1, Len("ext.")) = "ext."`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This expression does the work,

```
NewColumn =
IF (
    LEFT ( TableName[ColumnToSearchIn], LEN ( "Some string" ) ) = "Some string",
    "Starts With",
    "Does not start with"
)
```

This expression will determine if `ColumnToSearchIn` starts with `Some string`.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: "Some string" could also be stored in variable if the search text is long, or needs to be determined by a formula:
NewColumn =
VAR search = "Some string"
RETURN
IF (
    LEFT ( TableName[ColumnToSearchIn], LEN ( search ) ) = search,
    "Starts With",
    "Does not start with"
)

Answer (score -1):

you can use text functions

=FIND("BMX","line of BMX racing goods")

check

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634938.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634882(v=sql.120).aspx

Comment: yes but i want exactly starts with not find anywhere